# Как при наведении на ссылку в выпадающем меню сделать hover категории

Tags: html, css, hover

У меня в `categories` (Категории) перечислены `iPhone`,`iPad` итд. Так вот как сделать при наведении на `дроп лист` автоматом наведение на категорию. То есть если я навожу на `iPhone x` допустим, светился и `iPhone` тоже.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 90px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu:hover {
  border: 1px solid coral;
}

.categories a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.categories a:hover {
  color: coral;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid coral;
  color: coral;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.categories>li {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.submenu {
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

.submenu li {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.submenu li a {
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.submenu li:hover {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.categories li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid coral;
  border-bottom: 1px solid coral;
}

.categories button:hover+.submenu {
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="categories">
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">iPhone</button> </a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">iPhone X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">iPad</button></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">iPad Pro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad 2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad Mini</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad Air 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">Mac</button></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">iMac Pro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iMac 2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iMac 2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iMac 2015</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">Watch</button></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Watch Series 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch Series 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch Series 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch Series 3 (Edition)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">Accessories</button></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Apple Mini DisplayPort</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Мышь Apple Magic Mouse 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Apple USB-C Digital AV </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Трекпад Apple Magic Trackpad 2 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса, что значит  "hover категории" ?

Comment: у меня в categories (Категории) перечислены iPhone,iPad итд. Так вот как сделать при наведении на дроп лист автоматом наведение на категорию. То есть если я навожу на iPhone x допустим, светился  и iPhone тоже.

Comment: Позвольте написать код заново, у вас некорректно построена структура `html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Я не менял структуру и не менял вашу вёрстку** , но исправил и интересующий фрагмент css выглядит так :

```
li:hover a>.btn { border: 1px solid green;color: green;}
```

**и сама реализация такая** :

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 90px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu:hover {
  border: 1px solid coral;
}

.categories a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.categories a:hover {
  color: coral;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid coral;
  color: coral;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.categories>li {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.submenu {
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

.submenu li {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

li:hover a>.btn {
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: orange;
}

.submenu li a {
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.submenu li:hover {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.categories li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid coral;
  border-bottom: 1px solid coral;
}

.categories button:hover+.submenu {
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="categories">
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">iPhone</button> </a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">iPhone X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">iPad</button></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">iPad Pro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad 2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad Mini</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad Air 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">Mac</button></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">iMac Pro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iMac 2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iMac 2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iMac 2015</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">Watch</button></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Watch Series 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch Series 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch Series 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch Series 3 (Edition)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="btn" type="">Accessories</button></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Apple Mini DisplayPort</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Мышь Apple Magic Mouse 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Apple USB-C Digital AV </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Трекпад Apple Magic Trackpad 2 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я переписал код, суть в том что при наведении на `.category` ссылки изменяют цвет а так как `.submenu` потомок класса `.category` происходит наведение так-же и по `.category`. Я удалил `button` потому-что для кнопок меню лучше использовать просто ссылки.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #222;
}
.menu .categories {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu .categories .category {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.menu .categories .category a {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu .categories .category:hover a {
  color: #ff7300;
}
.menu .categories .category:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
.menu .categories .category .submenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.menu .categories .category .submenu li a {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu .categories .category .submenu li a:hover {
  color: #ff7300;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
   <ul class="categories">
      <li class="category">
         <a href="#" class="btn">IPhone</a>
         <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">iPhone X</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="category">
         <a href="#" class="btn">IPhone</a>
         <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">iPhone X</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>      <li class="category">
         <a href="#" class="btn">IPhone</a>
         <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">iPhone X</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>      <li class="category">
         <a href="#" class="btn">IPhone</a>
         <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">iPhone X</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>      <li class="category">
         <a href="#" class="btn">IPhone</a>
         <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">iPhone X</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8 Plus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone 7 Plus</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```